# how to get the old session?

Tags: php, session, captcha

I have a post form with captcha based on session for example the code know is Ujkd9 after refreshing the code become Hi8P4 .
And this is the problem. If someone post the form the captcha code of the input become old, how to get the old session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can't, but you could save the older session into another session key creating a copy of that session, by example :

$_SESSION['session_copy'] = $_SESSION['current'];

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your captcha code is being made on the fly and output via some image making in PHP. Your problem is that once you make the image and output it, you have no way to figure out what the CAPTCHA value actually is?

Since I have absolutely no knowledge of what your application structure, or database looks like, I can give you recommendations based on what I would do:

If I can assume that your PHP script looks something like this:

```
$captcha_string = make_hash(); // This function could just be the consolidation of your step in making the hash. I don't know, so it's going to be generic.

make_captcha_image($captcha_string); // Again, I don't know exactly how this goes, so I have to assume.
```

In layman's terms, you are going to need to store that somewhere. But Where? Now, I want it kept in mind that I've never particularly worked with Captcha directly, so I'm not 100% on what the "best practices" are, and I also don't know what you're doing, so these are probably going to be vague answers for a vague question. There are roughly 3 options, the way I see it.

## 1. Database Storage

Realistically, I would probably use a database as a first go-to. In my database I would have a table named captcha, with the following definition:
`CREATE TABLE captcha (captcha_id int unique not null auto_increment, session_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, captcha_string VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL)`
*Note:* I don't know what length the `session_id()` function will return, and I am currently unable to check. If you know how long the session id is, change the length on session_id to match. Similarly for `captcha_string` I don't know how many letters your captcha will have. Change the definition to fit your uses.

What you are going to do, in words is:

1. Query the database with the current session_id to see if a captcha image exists.
2. set the information in a variable, I am using `$captcha_data`
3. If $captcha_data is populated with information, use its captcha string, otherwise, create a new on and store it.

Note that for this example, I assume that your database connection, whatever type it is, sits in an object named `$db` I am using no particular type of database, just methods I use in my own database class. The definitions would look similar for yours, but probably not exact.

```
$session_id = session_id(); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM captcha WHERE session_id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($session_id)."'";
$result = $db->query($sql);
if($result!==false){
    $captcha_data = $db->fetchrow($result);
}
$db->free_result($result);



$captcha_string = (isset($captcha_data['captcha_string'])) ? $captcha_data['captcha_string'] : make_hash(); // This function could just be the consolidation of your step in making the hash. I don't know, so it's going to be generic.

if(!isset($captcha_data['captcha_id'])){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO captcha (session_id, captcha_string) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($session_id)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($captcha_string)."')";
   $db->query($sql);//You should check that this query is successful in your code, but for brevity I am skipping it.
}

make_captcha_image($captcha_string); // Again, I don't know exactly how this goes, so I have to assume.
```

Now keep in mind, I would probably add a date or time column to the captcha data so that I could delete values from accounts that haven't been used in some months, just to keep size down, but that's something I leave to you.

## 2. $_SESSION Storage

I can't say I recommend this option. It's effectively the same as my previous answer, just without the database interactions.

In words, we are doing the following:

1. Checking if the `$_SESSION['captcha_id']` value is set, if so, use it. If not, create it.

This code is going to look very odd, so I recommend looking up [Ternary Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
//Assuming your session_start() is at the top of the page

$captcha_id = $_SESSION['captcha_id'] = (isset($_SESSION['captcha_id'])) ? $_SESSION['captcha_id'] : make_hash();

make_captcha_image($captcha_string);
```

## 3. File System Storage

I'd like to say that if this is the option you're choosing you've got some life decisions to make. This should not be used. Ever. Seriously.

That being said, the basic premise here is

1. See if a file with the current session_id exists.
2. if it does, read it's contents and use them as the hash for the image
3. else, create a new hash, create and populate the data in the file.

*How that looks in Code:*

```
$session_id = session_id();
if(file_exists('temp/'.$session_id.'.php')){
  $captcha_string = $captcha_data = file_get_contents('temp/'.$session_id.'.php');
}else{
  $captcha_string = hash();
  file_put_contents('temp/'.$session_id.'.php',$captcha_string);
}

make_captcha_image($captcha_string);
```

Just to reiterate: don't use this method. I am supplying this answer simply and solely because your question asked HOW to keep the captcha from changing.